# Why string with hex format number convert to correct integer value? PHP

Tags: php, casting

I've found out unclear php behavior

```
echo '0x12' + 2; // 20
```

As I understand from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php string '0x12' should cast to 0 like '0b11' do

```
echo '0b11' + 1; // 1
```

Please explain why is it so.

UPDATE

First example give me 2 in 7.x and 20 in 5.x versions.

Comment: Any `string` is casted as `0` when doing an addition in PHP, hexadecimal or octal will not be interpreted, you get the same behavior with `echo 'lol' + 2; // 2`.

Comment: Okay, the edit gave its sense back to the question. When I test myself, I get the expected result, which is 2.

Comment: @AntoineB looks like it gives 2 in version 7.x, and 20 in 5.x

Comment: @DmitriPortenko [Backward incompatible changes for PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.strings.hex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [AntoineB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3876196/antoineb) and [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) for the comments. From this point I can conclude it was more like an issue in php 5.x rather then feature and fixed in php 7.x ([Backward incompatible changes for PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.strings.hex)).